# Obtain filename with extension on filepath returned by HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I am in the middle of writing a function to obtain the file list inside a particular directory in HDFS. My following code successfully obtain the list

```
val status = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path("/" + ownerId + folderName ))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath))
```

In x.getPath, I obtained a list of path

```
hdfs://localhost:54310/david/12345/account.csv
hdfs://localhost:54310/david/12345/iris.csv
```

How do I filter the path to obtain the filename account.csv and iris.csv? Note that I am developing in a local environment so there is a possibility that we may get something like below when deploy into remote server.

```
hdfs://localhost:54310/media/david/12345/iris.csv
```

which has a deeper path.

Comment: If you only need files , you can use `fileSystem.listFiles(Path, Boolean)`. Pass `true` for a recursive search. It returns an iterator.

Comment: I also need the file details such as isDirectory()/isFile() and getLen()

Comment: You only get files with this method and if I understand your question correctly, you don't need directories, do you? Each element of the iterator will be a `LocatedFileStatus`. You can call `getLen` and `getPath` on each element to get the size and path of that file respectively.

Comment: I need also display the child directory if exist as well. I kinda solved my problem with regex. Thanks for some precious information!

Comment: Great job! Make sure to post the answer here that helped you solve your problem so that it benefits someone facing the same issue in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do, no regex needed

```
val filepath = x.getPath().toString()
val filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getName`

```
val status = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path("/" + ownerId + folderName ))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath.getName))
```